# Convert different string date, into one single date format In mysql

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I have an column **create_date** in my sql table, datatype is **varchar(225)**. My problem is, in that column values are in different date formats Please check the attached Image
[image]

I want to create another column with **constant_date_format** using **create _date** column, is there way?

I have tried with mysql str_to_date function:

```
STR_TO_DATE(create_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

it is working if create_date column have same date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **case when** with regular expression

SELECT 
 CASE WHEN create_date REGEXP [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] THEN STR_TO_DATE(create_date, '%m-%d-%Y') 
   WHEN create_date REGEXP **Format** THEN STR_TO_DATE(create_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
 ELSE create_date
 END AS create_date
FROM TABLE_NAME

https://www.guru99.com/regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

If your data is like the one in the example, it's impossible to do that. Consider if you have a row in **create_date** with value `8.1.2017`: what's **constant_date_format** for that? It's `1/8/2017` or `8/1/2017`?

You have, at least, define a fixed day/month order in **create_date**. Then you can use `REPLACE` on **create_date** to make sure you always use slahses or dots, and finally `STR_TO_DATE` to convert to date. For example, if you decide that **create_date** have month before day, you can do:

```
STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(create_date, '.', '/'), '%m/%d/%Y')
```